# opencv python bindings coverage

Tags: python, opencv, binding

I know of some opencv C++ API functions and classes that don't have python bindings.

Instead of finding these, one by one, every time I need them -- which is annoying -- is there any document, site, way of knowing what part of opencv C++ API has or has not python bindings?

I mean a summary of the coverage. I know that in the online documentation you can see if a function or class has a python interface -- but even then sometimes I wonder if the documentation is updated and maybe there is a binding somewhere. I don't want to do a binding myself unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: [http://docs.opencv.org/](http://docs.opencv.org/) cover the functions through several pages, including the python bindings, but I guess you're looking for something more immediate?

Comment: yes, I know, I was just editing the question to clarify that I want a summary, not having to search each function or class individually in the documentation

Comment: also, you know you can `dir(cv2)`, right? It's not pretty, but it might be a start if you have to compile such a list yourself

Comment: I see. I guess I can use that when I want to see if a particular function has a binding. Although I still would like to have a higher level view of what areas are available or not.